# Android получение картинки с камеры в byte[] без предварительного просмотра

Tags: java, android, камера, android-camera

Как получить картинку с камеры телефона в виде `byte[]` без предварительного просмотра в через `Intent`? То есть надо, чтобы полученные `byte[]` можно было отправить через `Socket`.

Нужно что-то вроде следующего:

```
Camera i1 = Camera.open();
byte[] i2 = new byte[1024 * 1024];
//i1.takeScreenshot(i2); Записать картинку в байты i2
mySocket.getOutputStream().write(i2);
```

Comment: Очень надеюсь, что нельзя :)

Comment: Надо хоть как-то её отправить через сокет, не обязательно в byte конвертировать.

Comment: Для работы на всех телефонах сделать без предпросмотра не получится. На части телефонов камере можно подсунуть невидимый Surface и это поможет. Часть телефонов желает именно видимый surface, но вроде как surface 1х1 пиксель вполне себе работает. Некоторым нужен Surface полноценного видимого размера (нексус-с желает чтобы видимая поверхность preview шириной была не менее 8 пикселей, а высотой не менее 16).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, основная проблема сделать это без просмотра. Попробуйте так:

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
try {
    mCamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(10));
} catch (IOException e1) {
    Log.e(Version.APP_ID, e1.getMessage());
}

Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
mCamera.setParameters(params);
mCamera.startPreview();
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i(Version.APP_ID, "picture-taken");
    }
});
```